# Exporting to GLTF2 breaks character skinning

Tags: rigging, export, gltf

I am setting up a pipeline between Blender and Godot, and I've opted to use GLTF2 in order to do this. My plan is to create multiple animations in a single blender file (run, idle, attack) along with the rigged mesh and then export them all in a single file into Godot.

The animations, rigging, mesh, etc. all looks good in Blender, but when I export it the mesh breaks. Vertexes are pulled in weird directions. The skeleton and animations work fine, the problem is with how the mesh is attached to the bones.

The export works fine when I used Collada (I can re-import into blender and everything works), but it will not import into Godot. I am also aware of the Godot exporter addon for blender, but that breaks the animations themselves.

[image: Preview]

[image: Export Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the exporter itself, and was solved by upgrading from Blender 2.80 to Blender 2.93. The glTF 2 exporter has improved significantly between versions. For future people reading this, make sure you are using the most up-to-date version of the exporter (probably in the most recent stable release of Blender) and see if that solves whatever problem you have.